# Change the date format my identifying the date and month?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function date()
{
   var myDate=new Date(document.getElementById('date').value); //get the date from a textfield
var day=myDate.getDate();
    var month=myDate.getMonth()+1;
var yr=myDate.getFullYear();

      if(dateformat=="dd/mm/yyyy")         //checking the date format //
      {

        document.getElementById('date').value=day + "/" + month + "/" + yr;
      }
    else
     { 

     document.getElementById('date').value=month+"/"+day + "/" +yr;
     }
   }
```

This function onchange is written in onchange mehod of textbox date,on changing the textfield it should change the date format that is set by default.

If `dd/mm/yyy` is the format then change it in that format and if `mm/dd/yyy` then change in this format.My code does the changes, but it cannot recognize which is the month!

**For example..** if the date format is `mm/dd/yyy` and I type the date as `11/01/2001' (NOV -1 2001) it changes to`01/11/2011` which should not be done. 
But if I type 01-11-2001 (jan 1 2001) which is entered is correct ,but it changes to 11/01/2001

How can I change the code to correct this??? plz help!!!

Comment: "This function onchange is written" i can't find any function named `on change`. if user types `11/01/2001` how do you expect to find out which date formate he want to use..? you can't read his mind. that is why you've to set a default date format and ask the user to enter the input in that format. otherwise you've to give him an option to change the date format like a drop down or something.. your question seems very vague..

Comment: So what is the final targeted format?  `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: @T J onChange is html property <input type="text" id ="date" onChange="date()">

Comment: @KevinBowersox not only this format.there is an option to select 2 format dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy. according to that..

Comment: @Piya Post the html with the select.

Comment: <table>
   <tr><td class="ta-wid">Date Format</td><td id="ta-right-edit">
    <select class="date">
    <option>dd/mm/yyyy</option>
    <option>mm/dd/yyyy</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    </table>

Comment: an `input type="text"` element will always pass it's value as a string. One way or another you need to parse that string.

Comment: thanks to all for the help!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xj7K/2/)***
*Javascript Code*

```
function dateChange() {
    var e = document.getElementById("dateformat");
    var dateformat = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var myDate;
    if (dateformat == "dd/mm/yyyy") //checking the date format //
    {
        var value = document.getElementById('date').value;
        var format = value.split("/");
        myDate = new Date(format[2], format[1] - 1, format[0]);
        var day = myDate.getDate();
        var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var yr = myDate.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById('date').value = day + "/" + month + "/" + yr;
    } else {
        myDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
        var day = myDate.getDate();
        var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var yr = myDate.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById('date').value = month + "/" + day + "/" + yr;
    }
    document.getElementById('dateStr').innerHTML = myDate.toDateString();
}
```

Enter the date `01/02/2014` with `mm/dd/yyyy` in drop down the date would be **`Thu Jan 02 2014`**, now just change the drop down to `dd/mm/yyyy` the date would be **`Sat Feb 01 2014`**

Instantiating Javascript's Date object require this format `new Date(yyyy,mm,dd)`, so when you use `dd/mm/yyyy` you need to manually ex-change the `dd & mm` values...
[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: @Bhavik can you confirm for me that the Date() object actually allows for the mm/dd/yyyy format? I was confused as to why your 'else' was working without splitting the string. I did a test and it looks like the built in functionality of the Date() method allows for mm/dd/yyyy. Great answer by the way.

Comment: @RyanBrewer [check the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cd9w2te4%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) `new Date(year, month, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,ms]]]])`, _year, month and date_ are required and all others are optional...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you either don't have `dateformat` specified or you compare it wrong.

```
if(dateformat=="dd/mm/yyyy")
```

If that always returns `false`, you will always get the second option.

Make sure `dateformat` is visible in the `date()` function, and make sure it actually gets the value you want it to have.

Secondly - the new Date() function actually parses the date before you check for the date format. I think you might want to do it the other way around: parse the input date, check which format it is in, and then output the result.