# JQuery datepicker Alert when selection is not desired

Tags: jquery, datepicker, alert

I am using a text field on NinjaForms, having selected a datepicker on it.

What I need is to show an alert to the user when he/she select a date less than 2 weekdays from current date.

Does somebody help me with a code for that?

Comment: [This might help](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that. But I don't want to prevent user from selecting any date, so minDate and maxDate would not help. What I need is to alert (onSelect) user that the selected date is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/MnFRZ/) || [***Updated fiddle persisting the date***](http://jsfiddle.net/MnFRZ/1/) || [***Updated fiddle with 'dd-mm-yy' dateFormat***](http://jsfiddle.net/MnFRZ/8/)

You could calculate the date difference `onClose` event of the datepicker and can show alert as required..

jQuery Code:

```
$('#txt').datepicker({
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //ms*sec*min*hrs
        var today = new Date();
        var selected = new Date(selectedDate);
        var diff = parseInt((selected - today) / oneday);//difference between the two dates
        if (diff <= -14) {
            alert("Not Good... Two weeks have passed..");
            $('#txt').val('');//Remove this to keep the dates
        } else if (diff <= 14 && diff >= 0) {
            alert("Not Good... Please give us 2 weeks..");
            $('#txt').val('');//Remove this to keep the dates
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, spectacular! Thanks, it is working. Just 2 things, if you can help: 1) I need 2 weekdays, I meant, 2 business days (2 days, not considering saturdays and sundays). 2) After the alert is fired and the user click 'ok' on it, the date is being deleted on the text field. I just need to alert user that the date may be not good for delivery, but keeping the selected date. Would you help me achieve that. But thanks anyway. You are saving me!

Comment: @MauroLopes [_This answer might help getting working days_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9700612/2260614) and to persist the days see the updated answer... You have an alternative, 14 working days means 18 days(14 working + 4 weekend). Mark it as an answer, Might help someone else..!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I appreciated that. A question: do you know why I got "-3" for the question? Maybe I did something wrong and don´t know...

Comment: Hey man, would you update the code, so I get date in this format: dd/dd/yy ? I used - dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' - , but now I am getting alert saying that the date is in the past even when I select tomorrow or the day after tomorrow, por exemaple. I believ your code works only for mm-dd-yy format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MauroLopes I am not sure if `new Date(dd-mm-yy)` could work... [___I got a way around with this in my answer here___](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24034913/2260614)... See the updated answer... __And `-3` for the question because you didn't shared anything... [Read it out it might help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) __